# @scheduled annotation not working as expected in spring 4.0.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am using spring 4.0.2
The @scheduled annotation is not working properly in the given interval.
This is my code

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay=60*1000, fixedRate=60*1000) //60secs
    private void method() {
        System.out.println("Scheduled Task Running @"+new Date());
    }
```

And this is my output

```
Scheduled Task Running @Thu Sep 21 12:00:51 IST 2017
Scheduled Task Running @Thu Sep 21 12:00:57 IST 2017
Scheduled Task Running @Thu Sep 21 12:01:51 IST 2017
Scheduled Task Running @Thu Sep 21 12:01:57 IST 2017
Scheduled Task Running @Thu Sep 21 12:02:51 IST 2017
Scheduled Task Running @Thu Sep 21 12:02:57 IST 2017
```

My requirement is for every one minute the method should be invoked.
Its working, but after 6 secs of method invocation it's invoking the method again.
So the method was invoked twice in a minute. Can any one tell why its behaving like this? How can I solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: I just tested it (spring 4.3.9) and it works every 60 secs. Are you sure that you do not have the same scheduled method twice in your code?

Comment: Your code works in my system also . .

Comment: I am sure. I didn't have the method twice in my code. my spring version is 4.0.2. I will check with 4.3.9

Comment: You have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and a `DispatcherServlet`. Both have a `<context:component-scan />` or `@ComponentScan` scanning the same packages. Leading to initializing all your beans twice...